# Android Volley - how to parse long String in response

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm using Volley lib to handle http request. In response app receives really long json - object with base64 photo and few others information. Problem is I'm not receiving full json - when I try for example to print response or save it as string - response is being cut and not whole data is being saved. Here my code :

```
public static void customerFormData(Context ctx, final String security, final String hostess_id, final String hostess_session,final String language, final String place_id) {

        RequestQueue MyRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx);
        StringRequest MyStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(final String response) {

   Log.e(TAG, "onRespone: " + response);


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() { //Create an error listener to handle errors appropriately.
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onErrorResponseCustomerFormData: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        }) {
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> MyData = new HashMap<String, String>();
                MyData.put("action_type", "customer_form_data");
                MyData.put("hostess_id", hostess_id);
                MyData.put("security", security);
                MyData.put("lang", language);
                MyData.put("hostess_session", hostess_session);
                MyData.put("place_id", place_id);

                return MyData;
            }
        };
        MyRequestQueue.add(MyStringRequest);
    }
```

and response looks for example like this :

```
{"info":"Data correct.","customer_gender":{"1":"Female","2":"Male"},"customer_age":{"1":"18-25","2":"26-30","3":"31-40","4":"41-50","5":"50+"},"customer_nationality":{"3":"Arab","5":"Asian","2":"GCC","1":"Local","6":"Other","4":"Western"},"customer_brand_jti":[{"id_sku":"1","id_brand":"29","name_sku":"asd2","brand_name":"AWOLG","option1":"0","option2":"0","photo":"data:image\/png;base64,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
```

As you can see end of the json is not correct. How can I handle this issue ?

Comment: "response is being cut" -- how are you determining this? If it is via that `Log.e()` call, LogCat truncates what gets logged.

Comment: yes - this is via log.e but when I try to save it as a string it's exactly the same

Comment: You can debug it and can get the full string visible over there it will be cut it log due to limit of characters